# Creating leaderboards for sports and amateur leagues. Any sites?

Tags: webapp-rec

Im looking for a site that provides way to create and update online leaderboards for off-line competitions, such as entering scores for games you play with friends.

I currently use google spreadsheets / forms for this, but it is buckling under the number of records its tracking.

I can program, so if it has an api it would be even better.

Answer (score -1):

Some options:

- [ScoreBook.com](http://www.scorebook.com/)
- [OnlineScoreKeeper](http://www.onlinescorekeeper.com/)
- [Fixture List](http://www.fixturelist.com/)

Fixture List looks more like it's just for creating schedules. The other two seem like league management tools.

Answer (score -1):

[Rankade](http://rankade.com) probably suits your needs. My friends and I log every boardgame we play with all the scores, and the site automatically creates a ranking of all players. You can create different gaming leagues, and there are also [public pages](http://rankade.com/trepaste). It's free, and there are apps for iOS and Android (but I prefer the webapp, it has charts and more stuff).